Synchronizer Error - lscc.syscc: no such file or directory on Hyperledger Explorer
I am using Hyperledger Fabric v3.0.0. I want to monitor my network using Hyperledger Explorer. The network is up. When I start Explorer, the screen is as shown below.

I checked the logs of the explorer container with docker logs xxxexplorercontainerid the output is as follows:
[2024-11-21T12:02:03.592] [ERROR] Sync - <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Synchronizer Error >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

[2024-11-21T12:02:03.592] [ERROR] Sync - Error: error in simulation: failed to execute transaction d00a5575f86467db94ce1ba5e0dec11f0e837fd23b41c0ccc526128ee7c0a93e: could not launch chaincode lscc.syscc: error building chaincode: error building image: failed to get chaincode package for external build: could not get legacy chaincode package 'lscc.syscc': open /var/hyperledger/production/chaincodes/lscc.syscc: no such file or directory

It looks like Explorer can not reach the info of blocks, transactions, and chaincode. Any idea?

It looks like Explorer is trying to use the legacy (Fabric v1) chaincode lifecycle implementation (lscc); likely to list deployed chaincode. A new chaincode lifecycle was introduced with Fabric v2, and the legacy (Fabric v1) lifecycle was removed in Fabric v3. I guess that Explorer needs to be updated to use the newer (Fabric v2) chaincode lifecycle in order to be compatible with Fabric v3.

How do I update this? Is this something I can do myself or is it something the Hyperledger Explorer development team needs to do and release?

Somebody would have to contribute a code change to Hyperledger Explorer to change the way it queries for chaincode. The implementation looks to be in github.com/hyperledger-labs/blockchain-explorer/blob/main/app/platform/fabric/gateway/FabricGateway.ts

You're right @bestbeforetoday the code snippet that must change is 'async queryInstantiatedChaincodes(channelName)' function I think. The error log start at that point. I wish I was more competent in this matter and knew how to change it and contribute. It looks like I'll have to wait for someone to fix it and my time is running out. Thanks.

I have just realized that it is not only about chaincode lifecycle. Explorer also does not show the transactions created for channel creation, joining the channel, etc. What do you think?

I'm not certain of the reason for that. It might be that Explorer is written assuming there is an ordering service system channel, and this is another feature that has been deprecated for a while and is removed in Fabric v3
